# How to create an iOS Objective-C project with OpenCV

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

How does one create an iOS Objective-C Xcode project with OpenCV?

Answer (score 3):

Instructions based on; https://medium.com/@yiweini/opencv-with-swift-step-by-step-c3cc1d1ee5f1

### Part 1 (prepare Xcode for development)

- Download and install Xcode (these instructions are based on Xcode 10 Beta 4)
- Obtain IOS development app id (https://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/code-signing-your-app/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps/register-app-id)
- Register Device for iOS App Development;

  - e.g. [USERNAME]'s iPhone
  - UDID: [get from Xcode or iTunes]
- Create a CSR file (https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/create);

  - In the Applications folder on your Mac, open the Utilities folder and launch Keychain Access.
  - [Go to Keychain Access - Certificates - select "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" before requesting a certificate.]
  - Within the Keychain Access - Keychain Access drop down menu, select Keychain Access - Certificate Assistant - Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority.
- Create Development Provisioning Profile for iOS App (https://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/code-signing-your-app/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps/create-development-provisioning-profile)

### Part 2 (create a new Objective-C iOS project in Xcode)

- Product name: [INSERTYOURAPPLICATIONNAME]
- Team: Select [YOURTEAMNAME]
- Organization Name: [INSERTORGANISATIONNAME]
- Organization Identifier: [e.g. com.example]
- Do not 'Use Core Data'
- Language: Objective C (not Swift)
- OPTIONAL: create git repository on my Mac
- select [APPLICATIONNAME] project (blue document icon) in project navigator - [default target]
- General - Deployment info - Deployment Target - select an appropriate version for your device (e.g. 9.4)

### Part 3 (add OpenCV library)

- Download the opencv framework (https://opencv.org/releases.html , e.g. https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/3.4.2/opencv-3.4.2-ios-framework.zip/download )
- select [APPLICATIONNAME] project (blue document icon) in project navigator - [default target]
- Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries - Click the '+' - Add Other... - browse and select `opencv2.framework` (e.g. `/Users/[USERNAME]/Documents/libraries/opencv2.framework`)
- Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries - Click the '+' - add these additional frameworks (for opencv); AssetsLibrary, CoreGraphics, CoreMedia, CoreFoundation, Accelerate, [UIKit, Foundation, CoreVideo, CoreImage]
- Build Settings - Framework Search Paths - add `$(PROJECT_DIR)`
- Build Settings - Framework Search Paths - add `[INSERT COMPLETE PATH OF opencv2.framework]` (e.g. `/Users/[USERNAME]/Documents/libraries/`)
- File - New - File - Cocoa Touch Class. Name it `OpenCVWrapper` and choose objective-C for Language.
- `OpenCVWrapper.m` and rename the file extension to `.mm`
- manually change `OpenCVWrapper.m` to `OpenCVWrapper.mm` in the file header also
- Go to `OpenCVWrapper.mm` and add the following import statement on the top; `#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`